# How to compile Asciidoc document with "include" sections into a single adoc file

Tags: java, spring, asciidoc, spring-restdocs

I'm using the [spring-restdocs](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs) to generate a documentation for the project. The main `asciidoc` document includes other `adoc` snippets that describe `request`/`response` like:

```
include::{snippets}/projects/findOne_info/1/http-response.adoc[]
```

I'm using `gradle` and `asciidoc plugin` as described in [spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/1.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html5/#getting-started-build-configuration).

Having this, I can run `gradle` task to generate full documentation and get the `html` output.

What I want to do is that I want to include this documentation into `github wiki` as `asciidoc`, that's why I need to compile full documentation into `adoc` file instead of `html`. Is there a way of doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this script from the Asciidoctor extensions lab: https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-extensions-lab/blob/master/scripts/asciidoc-coalescer.rb. It's not perfect, but it's a start.